# How do you connect to a Samba share from macOS when using a Microsoft account?

Tags: macos, smb

I've set up Samba so that it uses the same username and password as my Microsoft account, so on Windows authentication is automatic when opening shares. However, with the same configuration I can't connect from macOS 10.14, getting an authentication error.

I'm serving from Ubuntu 19.04 with samba `4.10.0+dfsg-0ubuntu2.4`.

- There's a regular linux account for each user, with the username set to `user@example.com`.
- The linux accounts have the shell set to `/usr/sbin/nologin`.
- The password is set to the same password as the Microsoft account.
- Samba accounts have also been added, with the same user name and password.

When I connect from Windows 10, I see it sends a domain of `MicrosoftAccount` and it works fine. It also works fine from Samba's `smbclient`.

From macOS, it doesn't matter if I send `MicrosoftAccount\user@example.com` or `user@example.com` as the user name, it always sends the domain as `example.com` and auth fails. I see the same behaviour in the finder and with `smbview`.

I was able to work around this by adding `username map = /etc/samba/username_map` to `[global]` in `smb.conf`, with a line `user@example.com = user`.

Is there some config on the macOS side to make it respect the domain as specified? Or is this a standard config that most NAS and other units will use so they work with macOS?

**Edit:** Here's a log entry from a failed auth, trying as `microsoftaccount\user@example.com`. Of note is the first auth line showing example.com, and not `microsoftaccount` as the domain:

[2019/10/06 00:22:54.879743,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:552(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[microsoftaccount\user] domain=[example.com] workstation=[MAC] len1=24 len2=184

```
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.740866,  3] ../../lib/util/access.c:365(allow_access)
  Allowed connection from 192.168.20.104 (192.168.20.104)
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.741239,  3] ../../source3/smbd/oplock.c:1422(init_oplocks)
  init_oplocks: initializing messages.
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.741382,  3] ../../source3/smbd/process.c:1948(process_smb)
  Transaction 0 of length 73 (0 toread)
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.741464,  3] ../../source3/smbd/process.c:1541(switch_message)
  switch message SMBnegprot (pid 2332) conn 0x0
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.774931,  3] ../../source3/smbd/negprot.c:636(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [NT LM 0.12]
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.775036,  3] ../../source3/smbd/negprot.c:636(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [SMB 2.002]
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.775114,  3] ../../source3/smbd/negprot.c:636(reply_negprot)
  Requested protocol [SMB 2.???]
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.775380,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:294(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB2_FF
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.836522,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_spnego' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.836625,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.836700,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'gssapi_krb5_sasl' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.836786,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'spnego' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.836845,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'schannel' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837231,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'naclrpc_as_system' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837334,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'sasl-EXTERNAL' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837408,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837486,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'ntlmssp_resume_ccache' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837566,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_basic' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837639,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_ntlm' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837751,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'http_negotiate' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.837827,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'krb5' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.841888,  3] ../../auth/gensec/gensec_start.c:977(gensec_register)
  GENSEC backend 'fake_gssapi_krb5' registered
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.842332,  3] ../../source3/smbd/negprot.c:771(reply_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB 2.???
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.844972,  3] ../../source3/smbd/smb2_negprot.c:294(smbd_smb2_request_process_negprot)
  Selected protocol SMB3_02
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.874939,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62888215
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.879743,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:552(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[microsoftaccount\user] domain=[example.com] workstation=[MAC] len1=24 len2=184
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.879870,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:3872(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.880055,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:550(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.880219,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2786(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.880649,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[printers]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.880859,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[print$]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.881558,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[photos]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.881761,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  adding IPC service
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.882109,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:189(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [example.com]\[microsoftaccount\user]@[MAC] with the new password interface
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.882189,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:192(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [example.com]\[microsoftaccount\user]@[MAC]
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.882352,  3] ../../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'microsoftaccount\user' in passdb.
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.889113,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:334(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [microsoftaccount\user] -> [microsoftaccount\user] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, authoritative=1
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.889240,  2] ../../auth/auth_log.c:647(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [example.com]\[microsoftaccount\\user] at [Sun, 06 Oct 2019 00:22:54.889207 UTC] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER] workstation [MAC] remote host [ipv4:192.168.20.104:51103] mapped to [example.com]\[microsoftaccount\\user]. local host [ipv4:192.168.20.177:445]
  {"timestamp": "2019-10-06T00:22:54.889398+0000", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 1}, "eventId": 4625, "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.20.177:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.20.104:51103", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "example.com", "clientAccount": "microsoftaccount\\user", "workstation": "MAC", "becameAccount": null, "becameDomain": null, "becameSid": null, "mappedAccount": "microsoftaccount\\user", "mappedDomain": "example.com", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "duration": 14644}}
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.889565,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:2192(do_map_to_guest_server_info)
  No such user microsoftaccount\user [example.com] - using guest account
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.903462,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62888215
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.907333,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:552(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[microsoftaccount\user] domain=[SAMBA] workstation=[MAC] len1=24 len2=184
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.907430,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:3872(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.907519,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:550(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.907650,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2786(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.907903,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[printers]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.907995,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[print$]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.917347,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[photos]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.917663,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:1621(lp_add_ipc)
  adding IPC service
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.917730,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:189(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [SAMBA]\[microsoftaccount\user]@[MAC] with the new password interface
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.917852,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:192(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [SAMBA]\[microsoftaccount\user]@[MAC]
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.918003,  3] ../../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'microsoftaccount\user' in passdb.
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.918070,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:334(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [microsoftaccount\user] -> [microsoftaccount\user] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, authoritative=1
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.918190,  2] ../../auth/auth_log.c:647(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [SAMBA]\[microsoftaccount\\user] at [Sun, 06 Oct 2019 00:22:54.918167 UTC] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER] workstation [MAC] remote host [ipv4:192.168.20.104:51103] mapped to [SAMBA]\[microsoftaccount\\user]. local host [ipv4:192.168.20.177:445]
  {"timestamp": "2019-10-06T00:22:54.918332+0000", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 1}, "eventId": 4625, "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.20.177:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.20.104:51103", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "SAMBA", "clientAccount": "microsoftaccount\\user", "workstation": "MAC", "becameAccount": null, "becameDomain": null, "becameSid": null, "mappedAccount": "microsoftaccount\\user", "mappedDomain": "SAMBA", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "duration": 15008}}
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.918523,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:2192(do_map_to_guest_server_info)
  No such user microsoftaccount\user [SAMBA] - using guest account
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.931366,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_util.c:72(debug_ntlmssp_flags)
  Got NTLMSSP neg_flags=0x62888215
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.935125,  3] ../../auth/ntlmssp/ntlmssp_server.c:552(ntlmssp_server_preauth)
  Got user=[user] domain=[example.com@\samba.lan] workstation=[MAC] len1=24 len2=184
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.935213,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:3872(lp_load_ex)
  lp_load_ex: refreshing parameters
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.935573,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:550(init_globals)
  Initialising global parameters
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.935798,  3] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2786(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[global]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.936127,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[printers]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.936260,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[print$]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.936359,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
  Processing section "[photos]"
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.937227,  2] ../../source3/param/loadparm.c:2803(lp_do_section)
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.937520,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:189(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Checking password for unmapped user [example.com@\samba.lan]\[user]@[MAC] with the new password interface
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.937590,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:192(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  mapped user is: [example.com@\samba.lan]\[user]@[MAC]
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.937705,  3] ../../source3/auth/check_samsec.c:399(check_sam_security)
  check_sam_security: Couldn't find user 'user' in passdb.
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.937775,  2] ../../source3/auth/auth.c:334(auth_check_ntlm_password)
  check_ntlm_password:  Authentication for user [user] -> [user] FAILED with error NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER, authoritative=1
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.937878,  2] ../../auth/auth_log.c:647(log_authentication_event_human_readable)
  Auth: [SMB2,(null)] user [example.com@\\samba.lan]\[user] at [Sun, 06 Oct 2019 00:22:54.937855 UTC] with [NTLMv2] status [NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER] workstation [MAC] remote host [ipv4:192.168.20.104:51103] mapped to [example.com@\\samba.lan]\[user]. local host [ipv4:192.168.20.177:445]
  {"timestamp": "2019-10-06T00:22:54.937988+0000", "type": "Authentication", "Authentication": {"version": {"major": 1, "minor": 1}, "eventId": 4625, "logonType": 3, "status": "NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER", "localAddress": "ipv4:192.168.20.177:445", "remoteAddress": "ipv4:192.168.20.104:51103", "serviceDescription": "SMB2", "authDescription": null, "clientDomain": "example.com@\\samba.lan", "clientAccount": "user", "workstation": "MAC", "becameAccount": null, "becameDomain": null, "becameSid": null, "mappedAccount": "user", "mappedDomain": "example.com@\\samba.lan", "netlogonComputer": null, "netlogonTrustAccount": null, "netlogonNegotiateFlags": "0x00000000", "netlogonSecureChannelType": 0, "netlogonTrustAccountSid": null, "passwordType": "NTLMv2", "duration": 6752}}
[2019/10/06 00:22:54.938073,  3] ../../source3/auth/auth_util.c:2192(do_map_to_guest_server_info)
  No such user user [example.com@\samba.lan] - using guest account
```

And here's my smb.conf:

```
[global]
   log level = 3
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes

   # Mapping users for macOS clients
   # username map = /etc/samba/username_map

   # Netatalk support
   vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
   fruit:encoding = native
   fruit:resource = file
   fruit:metadata = netatalk
   fruit:locking = netatalk
   fruit:copyfile = yes
   ea support = Yes
   hide files = /.DS_Store/Network Trash Folder/TheFindByContentFolder/TheVolumeSettingsFolder/Temporary Items/.TemporaryItems/.VolumeIcon.icns/Icon?/.FBCIndex/.FBCLockFolder/

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no

[photos]
  comment = photos
  browseable = yes
  valid users = user@example.com
  force user = media
  writeable = yes
  path = /main/photos
  create mask = 0774
  directory mask = 0775
  inherit permissions = yes
```

Comment: Did you enable DFS? Turning that off if so might simplify things and the assumptions made on the windows side to use the log in credentials transparently.

Comment: Also - since you are running the share - you might want to tail the auth / error / smb log on the NAS when your mac clients connect - the issue should be pretty clear and easy if this is reproducible.

Comment: No, I'm not using DFS at all.

Comment: Good. That simplifies things greatly and makes this more likely to get a quick answer

Comment: I added the auth logs as well as my smb.conf.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have to do anything on MacOS other than open the finder and connect using Command K - connect to server.

When the dialog pops up, put in your UPN or domain\user.name@this.that and enter the correct password and optionally save to the keychain.

Anything you do to edit /etc files will complicate things, so I would roll those back. If you want to lightly bind the user account to a directory, you can look at things like Apple Enterprise Connect or [NomAD](https://nomad.menu/) or [Jamf Connect](https://www.jamf.com/products/jamf-connect/). Binding the mac to AD causes a lot of pain, so most pros avoid that now and use a different tool if you can’t just use the out of the box setup with Keychain.

My only guess at this point is you somehow need to federate the directory services on linux to ADFS / Microsoft online to get that pairing to work. This synology related article calls this transparent SMB authentication but I'm not sure if that's the correct term to search. The other question says it's using WinBind.

- https://blog.danic.net/enabling-transparent-smb-authentication-between-your-microsoft-account-and-your-synology-diskstation/
- [Macs Disconnect from SMB Share: "STATUS_NETWORK_SESSION_EXPIRED (0xc000035c)"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373563/macs-disconnect-from-smb-share-status-network-session-expired-0xc000035c)

Comment: To clarify, I haven't touched anything on the macOS side in `/etc`, and I was referring to the server side `smb.conf`.

Comment: Really, there's nothing needed on the server side or on the Mac side to make this work @deviantintegral Would you want us to migrate this to the ubuntu or linux site in case this is really about setting up the SMB side on linux? I'm not seeing anyone look at the answer or question and give any votes to either of us. 28 views in 30 days is going to be a long haul if the recent bump doesn't get some more votes and eyeballs.